# Запятая в описание действия для закрытия/открытия вопросов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

По-моему, переводчики не договорились, нужно ли писать запятую (и если нужно, то как) в [описании возможных действий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/) (жмем ссылку "(развернуть)") для закрытия/открытия вопроса перед "если" или нет:

[image: запятая ннада?]

Comment: В конце предложений тоже не хватает точек.

Comment: Если это список, то лучше ставить в конце предложений точку с запятой, кроме последнего пункта (там ставится точка).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На Transifex у нас есть две раздельные строки, разделенные жестко заданным пробелом. Теоретически, можно было бы добавить запятую после первого слова (можно сделать при необходимости).

*На данный момент, взял поясняющую конструкцию в скобки и добавил точку в конце*.

- **Оставить открытым** (если этот вопрос не следует закрывать).
- **Закрыть** (если данный вопрос следует закрыть по какой-либо причине; оставьте комментарий с объяснением, перед тем как проголосовать).
- **Правка** (если этот вопрос можно улучшить, чтобы не было необходимости закрывать его).
- **Пропустить** (если вы не уверены и хотите перейти к следующему вопросу).

Comment: Кнопка называется "Оставить открытым", а пункт будет просто "Оставить"? Или кнопка тоже поменяется?

Comment: @alexolut Это я ошибся, когда ответ писал. Строки остались прежними.

Comment: Возможно стоит учесть вариант @Qwertiy и убрать `если`, `этот`, `данный`. Кстати пункт `Правка`, имхо, должен называться `Править`, чтобы не выпадать из общего списка.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание! Поправил на «править».

Comment: Про «если», «этот», «данный» и т. д. как я понимаю, сообщество против.

Comment: "Против" из-за `-1` в соответствующем ответе?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: ну, это не показатель в данном случае.

Comment: Согласен, но других показателей не было.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41711/discussion-between-alexolut-and-nicolas-chabanovsky).

Answer (score 0):

Убрать слово "если" (вместе с "этот" и "данный") и поставить тире.